# Hide a specific warning in IE console window

Tags: angularjs, debugging, warnings, internet-explorer-11

I am working on an Angular project on a SharePoint 2013 site. When using the console window in IE 11, I see 75 warnings like this:

```
SEC7132: The certificate protecting this web site uses weak cryptography,
SHA1. The web site should replace this certificate with a SHA2 certificate 
before SHA1 is no longer allowed.
```

Now, please accept the premise that I have no control over my admins and I cannot force them to fix the certificate. I can't make the SOURCE of this warning go away.

I know I can disable showing all warnings. But I can't assume that my code will only generate errors, I will still have some warnings I want to see. How can I suppress a specific warning in the console?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. It has nothing to do with your code. It is Internet Explorer telling you on each request that the web server certificate using for the SharePoint zone you are hitting (IIS website) is using an obsolete and insecure algorithm. So best thing you can do, is make your admins aware they have some work to do :)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/4010323.aspx